# My range outlet is lying on the floor

Tags: electrical, receptacle, range

I would like to replace my old electric range but the outlet it is plugged in is lying on the floor (under the range) and not attached to the wall (see the picture). Does anybody know if this is a problem for the newer ranges? Do I need to move the outlet to the wall?
Thanks a lot!
[image: the picture of my stove outlet]

Comment: The only problem is it is not attached to the wall.

Comment: I prefer that the outlet be attached to the wall, but it isn't a requirement. At least not in my location.

Comment: @RMDman   I find those bigger outlets to be on the harder side to unplug/plug.  I would prefer to only fight with the plug, than the plug and outlet.  Think maybe code has something to say about also, but unsure.

Comment: @crip659, Agree, but find plenty that are just on the floor.  I anchor all that are in any of my homes, but haven't found a code that says it must be mounted to wall or floor. ( Haven't aggressively look for a code either.)  Maybe someone here will chime in on that.

Comment: @RMDman Can't identify brand in use, but I would expect most product installation instructions to be similar to Leviton https://leviton.com/content/dam/leviton/residential/product_documents/instruction_sheet/55050_Instruction_Sheet_EnFrSp.pdf which says to "mount outlet on wall or floor using 3 (three) wood screws".

Comment: I guess I just have to make sure that the range I purchase have enough space at the bottom.

Comment: @NoSparks, I was aware of the directions from the manufacturer. I was looking for any NEC that required the unit be anchored.

Comment: @Emin Ozkan,  Most all ranges have space at the bottom. It is when the outlet is too high that it becomes a problem.

Comment: @EminOzkan NEC 110.3 says to use only as included instructions say. It would be good to select your range now, most range installations have a diagram showing the acceptable zone that the receptacle needs be mounted. For instance this LG on page 6 shows only wall mount is acceptable https://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/LRE3023%203025_MFL57205804_EN%5B1%5D.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to turn the breaker to the stove off.

You can remove the cover by removing the screw that is in a pocket in the middle of the 3 blade slots.

With the cover off you will see there are a number of holes in the back of the outlet body.  You can use any of those to insert a screw and anchor the unit to the wall.  Place very low on the wall, ( try to hit the bottom plate of the wall framing.) and use at least 2 screws. Be sure that no screw heads touch any of the wires or holders.

Replace the cover. Install the plug and turn on the breaker .

You are done.

Comment: And before screwing it down make sure it doesn't interfere with the range when it's in the "pushed back" position.